# Ltspice easy DC LC circuit

Tags: capacitor, dc, ltspice, simulation, coil

I'm making this simulation of an LC circuit with DC. After simulating it with different simulators, it seems that LTspice is doing something wrong.  Also, if you mess with the simulation time, it keeps being around the same. All the values are the same: R=10 ohm, L=1H and Capcacitor=15uF, So both circuits are identical

[image: LTspice output]

[image: Falstad.com]

Comment: So what is node 003? Guess common to capacitor and inductor. How large is the inductor, anyway? Does the capacitor model include a leakage resistor?

Comment: LTSpice will calculate the steady state conditions first and, you are applying a step-transient (not DC) so, you need to tell LTSpice not to calculate the steady state conditions.

Comment: @greybeard Both cicuits are identical with values  R=10 ohm, L=1H and Capcacitor=15uF. No a leakage resistor won't be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the transient sim menu, check "Skip initial operation point solution" to start the sim with 0 V across the capacitor.

Comment: ...or add `ic=0` to the capacitor, or use the `.ic` command to set either initial voltages or current for the inductor, or the `startup` flag, or even make the source a `PULSE(0 5 0 1m 0 1k)` or `PWL(0 0 1m 5)`. The total simulation time can be reduced tenfold. If the quality factor is too high the timestep may need to be imposed, too.